# Why is it so that phloem parenchyma is absent in most monocots?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy

I am currently studying anatomy of flowering plants and came across this statement in my textbook:
*'Phloem parenchyma is absent in most of the monocots.'*

We learnt that the main function of phloem parenchyma is to store food material and other substances like resins, mucilage and latex. Do monocots have some other structures for the same purpose? Why is it that they lack these type of cells?

Comment: @MaximilianPress I did look up as many Q and A forums as I could (posting questions only after thorough research) and mostly the answers I saw didn't actually explain the reason and instead wrote it down as a fact. Answers on Quora especially , were very vague and not that helpful. I'll edit the question accordingly , thanks.

Comment: @MaximilianPress please don't recommend users look up info on such disreputable (and low quality) sites such as Quora.  -_-

Comment: @theforestecologist fair enough, deleting comment.